# Checking that a HTML element is not present

Tags: c#, automated-tests, watin

I'm doing UI testing using Watin (Watir, for java folks). I need to check that an element is not present in the HTML. As of today, I do this as follows:

```
    [FindBy(Id = "pnConfirmation")]
    protected Div Confirmation;

    public bool ConfirmationMessageDisplayed
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return Confirmation.Text != "";
            }
            catch (ElementNotFoundException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this takes an awful lot of time. Is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: removed watir tag since the question is not about it

Comment: Changed asp.net tag to C#, because this is connected to web page testing in general, but code is in C#.

Comment: Thanks guys! (I put the watir tag since I assumed both used the same logic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you call `Confirmation.Text` WatiN waits until element exists. After that time `ElementNotFoundException` is thrown. By default WatiN waits 30 seconds for element to show. This could be changed by setting value of `Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut`.

To solve your problem you can do several things. For example, you can change this line:

```
return Confirmation.Text != "";
```

to

```
return Confirmation.Exists && Confirmation.Text != "";
```

But you have to remember that this will return `false` even if this element will appear after 1 second. If you want to use that solution, I think that you don't have to catch this exception if you are sure, that once it's present, it will not be deleted.

You can of course change the value of `Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut`. If you don't want to change this value, but you want to wait only a little, you can replace your getter with this code:

```
try
{
    Confirmation.WaitUntilExists(1); //Wait only one second
    return Confirmation.Text != "";
}
catch (WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException) //Different exception!
{
    return false;
}
```